# How can i include functions from rootfiles in subfiles?

Tags: c, inheritance, methods, include, hierarchy

I am a beginner in C and I am struggling  with the following problem:

I have a main file called a.c

It includes a file b.c

b.c includes stuff from c.c and c.c includes stuff  from d.c

I did this because  I wanted to have a good structure in my code and because of the fact that all files have some methods and structures  in common  that I can consequently store in d.c

Now I only have one problem: I want to rewrite  a method in d.c but in this method  I need to call a method  from a.c.... this is not possible

Do you have a solution for that? Should I rather put everything  in one file even though  it would be a very bad structure? Or is there another way to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Whether to put code into a single file or into multiple files is usually a consideration made through experience. Rarely is it good to "always do X". However, always try to find the balance between coding fetishisms and practicality. I'm not sure whether you are really including .c files. If so, that's probably bad practice.

Comment: To add to what @Cheatah said, you should only be including header (.h) files. These include functional and type declarations, but not actual _implementations_ of the functions. Those are in source (.c) files. These get compiled and then linked together.

Answer (score 0):

If A depends on B and B on C and C on D and D on A, then you have a circular dependency.

A solution to this problem would be to introduce a new file, call it E and put all that stuff in there, which is in common with A and D.

The outline would look like this:

```
D
  \
   E
  /
A
  \
   B
    \
     C
      \
       D
```

With the proper use of [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), E should be included only once.

Comment: I've read the wikipedia article, but I still cant get along with these include guards.. I've now added a new file in which I put the method both files are using. Then I added the include guards as:  #ifndef E_H #define E_H  #include "A.h"   method(){ ... } #endif

Comment: Why do you include "A.h" in E? I thought we wanted to avoid that? I have a problem to understand, what you mean by "rewrite a function". Could you give an Example, what you want to achieve?

Comment: I will try to demonstrate it again: I have files A, B, C, D, E each of them include the next file, i.E: file A: include B; file B: include C etc.        What I now want to achieve is the following: I have a method in file E which is used by every file. So far so good, this works fine with this dependency, BUT now I want to access a method located in A from the file E. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Is an Example too much to ask? I asked you about "rewrite a function", you came along with "used by every file" and "to access a method". You cannot use nor access a method within a header file. What you can do is to **declare** a function and include other header files, where other functions are declared. The functions are **defined** in one or multiple source files. If you wish to invoke/call one of the functions you have to include the specific header file into your source. Since multiple declarations are not allowed: see my answer and the article about include guards.